# Arrogance vs arrogancy

Tags: grammaticality

What is the difference between arrogance and arrogancy? Do they mean the same thing?
which one sounds more correct and natural in the given examples:

1. Your arrogance is going to end you up nowhere.
   vs
2. Your arrogancy is going to end you up nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

"Arrogancy" is an archaic and rarely used synonym of "arrogance". It will sound or look unnatural to many native speakers.

> arrogancy
>
> noun
>
> same as arrogance
>
> Used Rarely.

[Arrogancy](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/arrogancy)